# Write JSON to firebase with custom encoder

Tags: python, json, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-admin

My python script scrapes a webpage and compiles the data to a large dict with three kinds of objects nested within.

This is the method I'm calling to write data:

```
firebase_admin.db.set(value)
```

*value* **must** be JSON-serializable.

Passing the dict as-is raises a TypeError.
Using json.dumps() to serialize with a custom encoder doesn't work, since it returns the dict as a JSON string which is then set as a single value at the root of the database.

So what I've come up is the following hack:

```
JSONDecoder().decode(CustomEncoder().encode(data))
```

Is it possible to somehow avoid this and pass the dict directly?

Comment: Interesting use case. The SDK does not support this today. But perhaps methods like `set()` should take an optional `data=` argument that takes the values in raw bytes. This is what `requests` does it seems. Can you file a feature request for this?

Comment: That sounds like an answer Hiranya! :-)